# Why got the error when run `ng build --prod`

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

Why got the error when run `ng build --prod`

When I use `ng-zorro-antd` v1.2.0 and angular v6.1.1, run `ng server` and `ng build` all work well.

But when I run `ng build --prod`, I got this error:

```
ERROR in : Unexpected value 'NzToolTipModule in 
/my-project/node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/antd.d.ts' 
imported by the module 'AdSidebarNavModule in 
/my-project/src/app/share/sidebar-nav/sidebar-nav.module.ts'. 
Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

I have no idea how to fix it now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove *NzToolTipModule* from sidebar-nav.module.ts because *NgZorroAntdModule* already imported that module.